# jQuery Chosen placeholder fallback options?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-chosen

OK,
I have jQuery chosen implemented, and it's working great. I am using the data-placeholder attribute as the drop down labels.

However, the only problem I am having is that if chosen is somehow disabled, (mobile, or JS disabled on the browser), then I have no labels on my drop downs...

I am looking for some way to fallback to a non chosen, non JS label.

I am guessing I need a way to detect if JS or Chosen is disabled, then triggering a css class???

Any suggestions and help would be greatly appreciated with this.....